# binding style into child component in vue

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I have a child component. I want to bind inline style into that component. I want to pass these style properties( height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll).

I have tried by passing like this:

**`<Childcomponent style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;" />`** but not working.

Then i have tried like this:

**`<Childcomponent :style="{'height': '200px'; 'overflow-y': 'scroll'}" />`** it is also not working.

How to bind inline style to this child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can do following:

```
<div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;">
   <Childcomponent />
</div>
```

If you want it to be done in your way, you have to create [prop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html)  in your component, pass styles into it and then apply those on tag inside of your component.

Like that:

In `Childcomponent` file add

```
prop {
   myStyles: String;
   ...
}
```

Those styles you will use in tag you want (I believe, in root one).
Then you can pass styles from parent in this way:

```
<Childcomponent my-styles="height: 200px; overflow-y: scroll;"/>
```